# Eclipse RCP- org.eclipse.ui.plugin missing

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I've written an Eclipse RCP application that runs fine in Eclipse, however, packaging it to be a standalone application has been tricky. I've worked my way though a few class path errors, but now I'm getting a new one.

After running the export wizard and launching my application, it throws a ClassDefError and  ClassNotFoundException, specifically it's looking for org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin. I did not find this in my copy of the eclipse SDK, and I downloaded the SDK again to be sure, and still couldn't find it. I found a jar online that supposedly contained the fiel along with some other eclipse packages, however, I then got this:

NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin: method ()V not found

I figure the problem is more I did something wrong rather than this class is actually missing, but I've gone though all the configurations and I'm sure all the required packages and dependencies are included. Any ideas?

Comment: To "package" it, are you using the Export wizard from your applications MANIFEST.MF editor?

Comment: No, I am using the one from the product configuration page.

Comment: Does your product configuration list all of the plugins you require?  Or is it feature based?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does, it lists all the plugins required to run it inside eclipse, and it list org.eclipse.ui but it does not list org.eclipse.ui.plugin (which I did not previously need and currently cannot find).

Comment: org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin is contained in the org.eclipse.ui.workbench plugin.  See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_a_particular_class_from_an_Eclipse_plug-in%3F

Comment: Ah. org.eclipse.ui.workbench is included in my classpath though, and I still seem to be getting this error, even on a fresh download of the eclipse sdk.

Comment: What do you mean, included in your classpath?  It should be listed in your .product file, but doesn't need to be in your MANIFEST.MF because `org.eclipse.ui` is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

Download and install the new version of adt plugin 21.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Does your application works when you run from Eclipse? If so then try to open your plugin.xml, go to **Runtime** and on the bottom right part of the window you should see **Classpath**. Try adding the required plugins there.